# REST Service call with JAR as payload

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate, asyncresttemplate

How to read JAR file from src/main/resources folder & use it as payload for REST service call from Spring boot application using RestTemplate

Any code snippet would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: Jar file is not different from any other file type in rest upload download. Why you want to treat differently?

Comment: hi Red Boy, Thanks a lot for your input, have updated the question the challenge I face is reading  the Jar file from resources folder and using it  in the payoad for rest service call

Comment: Please share what you have tried, its difficult for SO members to write a code for your qs.

Comment: Any Code / Github / add some code here in question. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `LinkedMultiValueMap` to send a file using RestTemplate, Code should be like below:

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("yourjarfile").getFile());

    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("file", new FileSystemResource(file));

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map,
                getHeaders());

    ResponseEntity<String> resp = new RestTemplate().exchange(
                    "REST_URL/", HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity,
                    String.class);
```